# C++ Const Pointer Comparison

Tags: c++, c, constants

I have been writing a project in `C`, due to a third party vendor who writes `C++` files with a `.C` extension I have had to add `-c c++` to my build. This is causing minor issues with some of my `C` function pointers. I am currently getting the error

```
error: comparison between distinct pointer types ‘void (*)(uint32_t)’ {aka ‘void (*)(unsigned int)’} and ‘const void (*)(uint32_t)’ {aka ‘const void (*)(unsigned int)’} lacks a cast [-fpermissive]
```

Here is my function.

```
bool scheduler_remove_task(const void (*TickFct)(uint32_t period_ms)) {
    bool task_removed = false;
    if(TickFct != NULL) {
        uint8_t i;
        for(i=0; i<MAX_TASKS; i++) {
            if(tasks[i].TickFct == TickFct) {  // ERROR on this line
                tasks[i].TickFct = NULL;
                task_removed = true;
                logger_log(&sch_logger, LOG_INFO, "Task %s removed", tasks[i].task_name);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return task_removed;
}
```

I get the pointers are seen as different types but why does the `const` keyword matter when I am only comparing values? What is different about `const` in C++?

Is there a way to keep my comparison without removing `const` from the arguments list?

Comment: This may be my first exposure to a function returning `const void`.  Following.  This is not about a "const pointer", by the way.  It's a non-const pointer to a function that has a `const void` return type.

Comment: `const` is used in wrong place. I bet plan was `void (*const TickFct)(uint32_t period_ms)` to be used as function argument.

Comment: Whar are your `tasks`?

Comment: Btw, you don't have to compile your C files as C++, even if you are using a C++ library. You only need to make sure that the header files used between the two are compatible to both languages. You can build each source file individually as C or C++ as appropriate and link all together at the end. And if this doesn't work, e.g. because the library uses C++ features in its headers or doesn't use `extern "C"`, then it would probably be better to write a C wrapper around the C++ library and use that.

Comment: @user17732522 But the library's header needs to use `extern "C" { ... }` when declaring the functions so you can call them from C.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, if the library doesn't do that, then it can't be used directly in a C project.

Comment: That was a lot, very quickly. @MarekR you are correct.

Comment: For everyone else. I have third party code with .C files that include <vector> and other libraries.

Answer (score 3):

`const void (*TickFct)(uint32_t period_ms)` declares `TickFct` as a pointer to a function which returns `const void`. This is a different function type than `void(uint32_t)`.

You want a const-pointer to a function that returns void: `void (*const TickFct)(uint32_t period_ms)`.

Or that might be clearer with a type alias:

```cpp
// typedef void(* tick_fc_t)(uint32_t period_ms);  // C-style
using tick_fct_t = void(*)(uint32_t period_ms);

bool scheduler_remove_task(const tick_fc_t TickFct) {  // ...
```